# Iterating two arrays, without nditer, in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, numpy

Consider a specification of `numpy` arrays, typical for specifying `matplotlib` plotting data:

```
t = np.arange(0.0,1.5,0.25)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
```

Basically, this stores the `x` coordinates of our `(x,y)` data points in the array `t`; and the resulting `y` coordinates (result of y=f(x), in this case `sin(x)`) in the array `s`. Then, it is very convenient to use the `numpy.nditer` function to obtain consecutive pairs of entries in `t` and `s`, representing the `(x,y)` coordinate of a data point, as in:

```
for x, y in np.nditer([t,s]):
  print("xy: %f:%f" % (x,y))
```

So, I'm trying the following snippet as `test.py`:

```
import numpy as np
print("numpy version {0}".format(np.__version__))
t = np.arange(0.0,1.5,0.25)   ; print("t", ["%+.2e"%i for i in t])
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)         ; print("s", ["%+.2e"%i for i in s])
print("i", ["% 9d"%i for i in range(0, len(t))])
for x, y in np.nditer([t,s]):
  print("xy: %f:%f" % (x,y))
```

... and the results are:

```
$ python3.2 test.py 
numpy version 1.7.0
t ['+0.00e+00', '+2.50e-01', '+5.00e-01', '+7.50e-01', '+1.00e+00', '+1.25e+00']
s ['+0.00e+00', '+1.00e+00', '+1.22e-16', '-1.00e+00', '-2.45e-16', '+1.00e+00']
i ['        0', '        1', '        2', '        3', '        4', '        5']
xy: 0.000000:0.000000
xy: 0.250000:1.000000
xy: 0.500000:0.000000
xy: 0.750000:-1.000000
xy: 1.000000:-0.000000
xy: 1.250000:1.000000

$ python2.7 test.py 
numpy version 1.5.1
('t', ['+0.00e+00', '+2.50e-01', '+5.00e-01', '+7.50e-01', '+1.00e+00', '+1.25e+00'])
('s', ['+0.00e+00', '+1.00e+00', '+1.22e-16', '-1.00e+00', '-2.45e-16', '+1.00e+00'])
('i', ['        0', '        1', '        2', '        3', '        4', '        5'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    for x, y in np.nditer([t,s]):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'nditer'
```

Ah - it turns out, that [the iterator object nditer, introduced in NumPy 1.6](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#arrays-nditer), is not available in the `numpy` version of my Python 2.7 installation.

So, as I'd like to support that particular version too, I'd need to find a way working for older `numpy` - but I'd still like the convenience of just specifying `for x,y in somearray`, and getting the coordinates directly in the loop.

After some messing about with `numpy` documentation, I came up with this `getXyIter` function:

```
import numpy as np
print("numpy version {0}".format(np.__version__))
t = np.arange(0.0,1.5,0.25)   ; print("t", ["%+.2e"%i for i in t])
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)         ; print("s", ["%+.2e"%i for i in s])
print("i", ["% 9d"%i for i in range(0, len(t))])

def getXyIter(inarr):
  if np.__version__ >= "1.6.0":
    return np.nditer(inarr.tolist())
  else:
    dimensions = inarr.shape
    xlen = dimensions[1]
    xinds = np.arange(0, xlen, 1)
    return np.transpose(np.take(inarr, xinds, axis=1))

for x, y in getXyIter(np.array([t,s])):
  print("xyIt: %f:%f" % (x,y))

for x, y in np.nditer([t,s]):
  print("xynd: %f:%f" % (x,y))
```

... which seems to work fine

```
$ python2.7 test.py 
numpy version 1.5.1
('t', ['+0.00e+00', '+2.50e-01', '+5.00e-01', '+7.50e-01', '+1.00e+00', '+1.25e+00'])
('s', ['+0.00e+00', '+1.00e+00', '+1.22e-16', '-1.00e+00', '-2.45e-16', '+1.00e+00'])
('i', ['        0', '        1', '        2', '        3', '        4', '        5'])
xyIt: 0.000000:0.000000
xyIt: 0.250000:1.000000
xyIt: 0.500000:0.000000
xyIt: 0.750000:-1.000000
xyIt: 1.000000:-0.000000
xyIt: 1.250000:1.000000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 23, in <module>
    for x, y in np.nditer([t,s]):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'nditer'
$ python3.2 test.py 
numpy version 1.7.0
t ['+0.00e+00', '+2.50e-01', '+5.00e-01', '+7.50e-01', '+1.00e+00', '+1.25e+00']
s ['+0.00e+00', '+1.00e+00', '+1.22e-16', '-1.00e+00', '-2.45e-16', '+1.00e+00']
i ['        0', '        1', '        2', '        3', '        4', '        5']
xyIt: 0.000000:0.000000
xyIt: 0.250000:1.000000
xyIt: 0.500000:0.000000
xyIt: 0.750000:-1.000000
xyIt: 1.000000:-0.000000
xyIt: 1.250000:1.000000
xynd: 0.000000:0.000000
xynd: 0.250000:1.000000
xynd: 0.500000:0.000000
xynd: 0.750000:-1.000000
xynd: 1.000000:-0.000000
xynd: 1.250000:1.000000
```

My question is - is this the way, this kind of iteration is supposed to be done, in versions of numpy < 1.6.0?

Answer (score 5):

How about [concatenating](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html) the two vectors into an array:

```
for x,y in np.c_[t,s]:
    print("xy: %f:%f" % (x,y))
```

This gives

```
xy: 0.000000:0.000000
xy: 0.250000:1.000000
xy: 0.500000:0.000000
xy: 0.750000:-1.000000
xy: 1.000000:-0.000000
xy: 1.250000:1.000000
```

If you want to iterate so you can save memory, you can use the [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) function:

```
for x,y in itertools.izip(t,s):
    print("xy: %f:%f" % (x,y))
```

Answer (score 3):

`for x, y in zip(t,s):`. For 1d arrays, it's really that simple.

Verified to work in both Python 2 and Python 3. zip() returns a list on Python2 though, so as DiggyF suggests, `itertools.izip()` may be more appropriate for large arrays.

For >1D arrays, iteration moves through the last dimension returning (N-1)D arrays. If you have to deal with N-d arrays, this may or may not be what you want.

Regardless, it's unquestionably portable, and iterating on array objects is intended to support this kind of usecase :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
x = x.flatten()
y = y.flatten()
for i,j in zip(x,y):
     #do something
```